# import.io crawler for non-standard system of pagination

Tags: import.io

I am trying to build an import.io crawler for this site http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/  but when I click "next" to get to next page to train, it takes me back to the first page because of the system of pagination being used. Would appreciate any suggestions on how to get the import.io crawler to crawl through these pages.  As suggested on import.io website I tried to find the system of pagination in the packets being exchanged with server but did not succeed. Thanks if you can help. JRH

Answer (score 0):

I used Bulk Extract to create an API.

https://import.io/data/mine/?id=bc7d67f2-24d3-4b5c-b134-01544430998a

If you use the offset pagination below you can input it into Bulk and get the data you need.

```
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1418833411427    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1409932229141    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1402342675828    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1397601000000    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1397511000000    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1390543200000    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1375383600000    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1359748800000    
http://theaccelblog.squarespace.com/?offset=1285959600000
```

Thanks,
Meg